# NodeJs POST request ER_DATA_TOO_LONG

Tags: node.js, post, request

I'm trying to add a post request to a website but i don't understand the error i'm getting. I'm sending four text element, I'm sure that they are right (size, type) and I manage to add an element manualy in my database without problem. It is not my website, I don't really know how it work so i replicated another request. However the error is saying that one of my element is too long which is not the case so i'm kinda confused.

Here is my POST request

```
app.post("/api/addOS" , function(req, res) {
    if(!(apikeys[req.query.username]===req.query.apikey) || (req.query.username == undefined) || (req.query.apikey == undefined)) {
        res.json({"error" : "not allowed"});
    } else {
        var con = new Database();
        var query = "INSERT INTO BRAND (name,abbr,color,type) VALUES ('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.abbr+"','"+req.body.couleur+"','"+req.body.type+"')";
        con.query(query).then(rows => {          
            res.json(rows);
        });
    }
});
```

The class Database is defined as follow

```
class Database {
constructor(  ) {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection( {
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "pswd",
      database: "dbname"
  } );
}
query( sql, args ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
            if ( err ){
                return reject( err );
            }
            resolve( rows );
        } );
    } );
}
close() {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        this.connection.end( err => {
            if ( err )
                return reject( err );
            resolve();
        } );
    } );
}
```

}

The error displayed on my webpage console is this one

> angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://localhost:4443/api/addOS?username=test&apikey=z4oP>3Jocv","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"name":"testtest","abbr":"test","type":"os","couleur":"tre"},"statusText":""}

and the one on my console is this one

> (node:15728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'abbr' at row 1
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
>       at Parser._parsePacket (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
>       at Parser.write (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
>       at Socket. (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
>       at Connection.query (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:201:25)
>       at C:\wamp64\www\node\app.js:92:29
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Database.query (C:\wamp64\www\node\app.js:91:16)
>       at C:\wamp64\www\node\app.js:379:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   (node:15728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:15728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: what type is `abbr` field and how many symbols it's length is? or don't send data longer than 2 or 3 symbols (since `test` is 4 char long and it's long for `abbr` field)

Comment: @num8er abbr is type varchar(8) I also already tried with less char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see common level issues:

1) never create connection to database on request time.

2) Your database class allow use of promises with args substitution (`?` symbols in my example), so use it, it's more secure.

You said `abbr` field is `varchar(8)` so `req.body.abbr.trim()` in my example must clean empty symbols that maybe was the issue.

Please try this code and tell me results.

```
const db = new Database(); // Connection must be created once

// authorization
const isAuthorized = function(req, res, next) {
  if(
   req.query.username && 
   req.query.apikey && 
   apikeys[req.query.username] === req.query.apikey
  ) {
    return next();
  }

  res.status(401).json({"error" : "not authorized"});
};

app.post(
  "/api/addOS", 
  isAuthorized,
  async function(req, res) {
    try {
      const result = await db.query(
        'INSERT INTO BRAND (name, abbr, color, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [req.body.name, req.body.abbr.trim(), req.body.color, req.body.type]
      );
      res.status(201).json(result);
    }
    catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({message: error.message});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to work now. I really hate having to take back the code of someone else 5 year after. the problems are always weird.